# How to inset items into list at sepcified intervals to match len of another list?

Tags: python, list

I have wrote a code which insert/duplicate items into list of smaller `len` to match `len` of bigger list.
code is:

```
l1=[big list of length:491]
l2=[small list of lenth: 153]
l= abs(len(l2)-len(l1))==> 338
i=0
j=1
while i<l:
    l2.insert(j,l2[j])
    j+=2
    i += 1
```

But after some loops i get this error

`IndexError: list index out of range`
which is because `l>len(l2)` and the code/algo catches up to len(l2).
Is there a better solution to solve this?

what i am expecting is
`l1` is any list of size 30 for example and `l2=[1,2,3,4,5]` output should be like `[1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5]`

Comment: Its not clear what you want to do with the smaller list. You want to fill it until both list has the same length. But with which values you want to fill the smaller list?

Comment: To make it more clear provide sample input data and expected output

Comment: @raze92 updated

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar i have updated my question, maybe this provide a better picture.

Comment: @tsu90280 if l1 is of size 30 then why l2 is of size 10 only?

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar  i am getting lists like that from an API call

Comment: `l2[i]` in the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this solves your requirements:

```
l1=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
l2=[11, 12, 13, 14, 15]

# Quotient of the lengths of both lists
quotient = float(len(l1)) / float(len(l2))

new_l = []
for i in range(len(l1)):
    # Divide the quotient from the index to get value of l2 which will be added. 
    new_l.append(l2[int(i/quotient)])

print(new_l)
```

Ouput:

```
>> [11, 11, 12, 12, 13, 14, 14, 15]
```